# pre decrement operator not working in dart null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
if (cart.quantity! > 1) {
  --cart.quantity;
```

[image]

this block of code works in previous flutter version after migrate to null safety it's not working anymore. How to properly write pre decrement operator in dart null safety

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113.  Additionally note that [only local variables can be type-promoted](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#property-or-this).  In the meantime, you'll need to use `cart.quantity = cart.quantity! - 1;`.

Comment: You should first check using `if` u have null value inside your `cart.quantity`. `if(cart.quantity != null) --cart.quantity;`

Comment: You can't use Composite Assignment yet check out the link https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/53f3e4606f7efe25679c37698e167734df7f934c/working/1113%20-%20null-asserting%20compound%20assignment/proposal.md

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (cart.quantity! > 1) {
  cart.quantity = cart.quantity! - 1}
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?